# Is there a common color file including all common colors for Android application development?

Tags: android, coding-style, colors

It is a common thing to add a color name and a color RGB value in a config xml file for developing an Android application. It is boring sometimes for example, when I want to add color pink, I had to find some tool to show me what the exact RGB value for it and then fill it in that xml file.

I am wondering is there any predefined color file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html ?

Answer (score 1):

See [Android .xml files: Why do predefined colors not work for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963978)