# Android .xml files: Why do predefined colors not work for me?

Tags: android

When I look at misc. Android tutorials and examples when it comes to specifying colors I very often see constants like `@color/red` or `@color/black` etc. being used. For some strange reason that NEVER works for me! I always need to specify colors using the "#RGB", #ARGB, ..., #AARRGGBB notation.

As soon, as I try to use any of those mnemonic constants like e.g. "@color/red" I am getting error messages like these:

```
[...] C:\Users\mmo\Test\res\drawable\edit_text.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/orange').
[...] C:\Users\mmo\Test\res\drawable\myDrawable.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/black').
[...] C:\Users\mmo\Test\res\drawable\myDrawable.xml:4: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/black').
[...] C:\Users\mmo\Test\res\drawable\myDrawable.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/green').
[...] C:\Users\mmo\Test\res\drawable\myDrawable.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'drawable' with value '@color/black').
```

Why is that so? Why can't I use these predefined constants? Do I need to prefix them with some package name (I tried `@android:color/red` but that only caused a different error)?
Do I need to specify these colors myself? If so: how and where? Any ideas or suggestions?

Michael

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Is "colors.xml" added to your res/values folder where these color constants are defined?

Comment: I created such a file in my app now and defined a bunch of default color there and now I can indeed use such named colors. Apparently all those examples I have seen assumed the existance of such a file without ever explicitly stating that. Thus I falsely had come to the conclusion that these values were predefined.

Answer (score 68):

If you want to use the colors pre-defined in the Android platform, the syntax is `@android:color/white`. The `android:` at the beginning indicates that the resource is not part of your application.

Comment: Nope, as I already wrote above: that doesn't work - at least not for me. Is there any special setting or "import" (or whatever) required to make this working?

Comment: Actually, I just had to learn, that this DOES works, but apparently only the "colors" @android:color/white and @android:color/black are defined. All others I tried (like @android:color/red, @android:color/green, @android:color/blue, etc.) yielded errors. Very odd!

Comment: It's only odd if you expect these colors to be defined by the platform, they are not. Usually if you see a sample app with @color/ that means the color was defined in the app itself.

Comment: If these are defined, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#constants then I would expect the XML values to be pre-defined as well.

Comment: well, I would expect to have at least the RGB components color defined by the platfom

Comment: @Chloe, That list is wrong. The correct one is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html . (Ctrl-Space to see the possible values.)

Answer (score 7):

Color XML file is within the values folder where it must contain color values.within resources tag.

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
```

Comment: should be  <color android:name="green">#00ff00</color>

Comment: No need to declare the namespace `xmlns` cause android resources files don't need the `android:` prefix.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your color XML file is within the **values** folder, not a **colors** folder.

So you should have...

***values**/colors.xml*

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

and NOT this...

***color**/colors.xml*

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</selector>
```

Note that the tag is **resources**, not **selector**.

Answer (score 3):

strangely Android does not provide a decent list of colors. And I say strangely because during my 30 years career this is the first language I met that does not do that. And that despite that is built on Java which defines colors in all it's basic libraries.

The ones that are defined are prefixed so you will not find them :)
To find them (if using eclipse ) go to the xml doc where you need the color 
type android:background="@android:color/ and do a Ctrl Space. 
On my version (current as we speaking) I get more than a dozen.
for instance: holo_orange_dark

So, use that or complain so Google fixes this issue. And I call it issue because it makes no sense to force all developers to manually describe all colors and values.

Comment: "this is the first language I met that does not do that" - what do you call "language"?

Comment: I agree. This is the first environment I've worked in that didn't have pre-defined colors but does define black/white/transparent. This is weird, I agree, but apparently true. This is why it is confusing to people that have been around a long time. To make it worse, there's not real good description I can find in the official docs. You just need to google around. Weird.

Answer (score 1):

An important part of this that no one else has mentioned is that the reference to the color has to be

```
@color/black
```

but the xml file has to be

```
colors.xml
```

(note plural in the xml file name but not plural @color)

Comment: -​1, **No** the filename can be anything. What is important is the tag name must be `color`, e.g. `<color name="green">#00ff00</color>`

Comment: Well noted. Change the value at lauch_backgroud.xml.