# Android Studio does not find color style resource

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to use a custom with **Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar** but the `IDE throws` the error that the named resources cannot be found. Kindly assist.Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The styles.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryLight">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/primary_text</item>
        <item name="textColorSecondary">@color/secondary_text</item>
        <item name="iconColor">@color/icons</item>
        <item name="dividerColor">@color/divider</item>
    </style>    
</resources>
```

The colors.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="primary">#FF9800</color>
    <color name="primary_dark">#F57C00</color>
    <color name="primary_light">#FFE0B2</color>
    <color name="accent">#03A9F4</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
    <color name="secondary_text">#727272</color>
    <color name="icons">#212121</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: I think your color xml name is colors and you call in color.. so it is not find

Comment: you can only reference the colors as '@color/colorname', it doesnt accept  '@colors/colorname'

Comment: @Destro thats not the problem

Comment: @Kabs have u added `appcompat-v7` dependency ?

Comment: yeah, i'm using 'compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

Comment: Is the file under folder /res/values ?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271387/get-color-int-from-color-resource

Answer (score 13):

Just **`Build > Clean Project`** Then **`File > Invalidate Caches / Restart Project`**.

Answer (score 2):

Rename Your xml Name, Set `color.xml` instead `colors.xml` under values folder. Then **`Build > Clean Project`** Then `Restart Project` .

Or try this way

```
 <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<color name="green">#00ff00</color>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963978/android-xml-files-why-do-predefined-colors-not-work-for-me)

Comment: it still throws the same error even after renaming the xml  file

Comment: @Kabs your color XML file is within the values folder?

Comment: yeah, it is @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/samples/BasicMediaRouter/res/values/colors.html

Comment: Thanks, that worked, though I don't find the reason for using the integer-array reference the defined colors

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have any imports like mine below

`import android.R`

This imports the wrong resource.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the following error which seems to be similar to yours

> error: resource color/color_primary (aka com.example.android.test31july:color/color_primary) not found.

I went to colors.xml and created exactly the color resource named "color_primary" and the problem vanished.

Comment: For me, it the colors.xml had a reference that didn't exist. I fixed the reference, and cleaned the project to make the error disappear. What Kumar wrote should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuilding can take a long time.

**Simply remove the offending line and re-add it.**

Answer (score 0):

make sure you use the color tag instead of any other tag.

```
<color name="name">#123</color>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.red800)
```